# Jupyter Notebook Opening but no contents are visible

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, prompt

Screenshot of Jupyter Notebook Session:

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter Notebook Session]

I am trying to launch a Jupyter notebook using anaconda prompt. The browser session opens but no contents are visible on the page.

Does anyone have any idea how to mitigate this?

Screenshot of Anaconda Prompt:

[image: Screenshot of Anaconda Prompt]

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467
I encounter similar trouble. So I just do 3 steps:
(1) uninstall Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6
conda uninstall notebook
(2) install old version
conda install notebook=5.7.4
(3) After lauching Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4
Press CTRL+R or CTRL+Shift+R to clear the cache
Then Jupyter Notebook works normally now.
Hope it's helpful to you.