# Encounter Simliar Trouble of Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Before yesterday noon, I used Jupyter Notebook without any trouble. However, at lunch time yesterday, I upgrade all packages in Anaconda3 by running "conda upgrade --all." Since afternoon yesterday, I can't see any content by running Jupyter Notebook.
Someone encountered similar trouble yesterday like
(1) [Jupyter Notebook Opening but no contents are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176162/jupyter-notebook-opening-but-no-contents-are-visible)
(2) [Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6 (last update) shows blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195384/jupyter-notebook-5-7-6-last-update-shows-blank-page)
(3) [Jupyter Notebook's default page appears nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180100/jupyter-notebooks-default-page-appears-nothing)
but have no solution yet.

Does it mean that Jupyter Notebook version 5.7.6 is defective? Otherwise, how to fix it?

[Lauch Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHDhl.png)
[No content is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGTJW.png)
[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOdlL.png)
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laAWc.png)